# Vs Code: How can I use the run code command to query my database?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

In Vs Code there is a play icon on the top right of the window that when clicked runs the code in the opened file. I have a development server opened on my laptop.

Can I query my Db with the run code command?

For example, I have a file with code as seen below(I am using nodejs and mongodb via mongoose):

```
async function getUsers(){
    try{
        let Users = await User.find({})
        console.log(Users)
    } 
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

getUsers()
```

Everytime I run the VsCode *run code* command I do not see any any results or error logged to the console. How can I see them? Is it possible to query the DB this way? If not, how can I test my DB queries without involving the front end?

***------------EDIT------------***

1. All I see in the console is : `[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.583 seconds`
2. After trying again and again I am now getting the error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`
3. After removing the await I am now getting the mongodb query object returned to me rather than the results.
4. After returning the `await` key word and changing my code to look like below now I am getting `Promise { <pending> }` as the result.

   ```
   async function getUsers(){
       try{
           let U = await User.find({})
           return U;
       } 
       catch(err){
           console.log(err)
       }
   }

   console.log(getUsers())
   ```

How can I resolve the promise and see the results?

Comment: Are you talking about the builtin debugger or about some third-party extension like Code Runner?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to ask. Querying the database in the code? You are already doing that. Querying the database without front-end? You log to console which is already being done. This question needs elaboration

Comment: I am not sure. It is a play button icon that has a tool tip saying "run code `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `N`"

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It is the [code runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni I can not see the log in the console. That is what I am trying to figure out why. No errors or results.

Comment: But... Does your code work to begin with? What you've shared is a function definition which you don't invoke.

Comment: My code works I had just not put the full code in the question, sorry my mistake. I have updated the question. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Do you save the file (`Ctrl` + `S`) after making changes? Code Runner ignores unsaved changes.

Comment: Yes. I save. Does code runner runner work with async/await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [MongoDB for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb) extension.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvcOYitD8Pw) explains how to set it up.

You can read more about it in the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-vscode/).