# VSCode: Using the code runner extension with mongoose promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, visual-studio-code, promise, vscode-code-runner

How can I use mongoose promises with the [vscode code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. Consider the code below.

```
async function getUsers(){
    return await User.find({}).exec()
}

console.log(getUsers()) //returns Promise { <pending> }
```

Why is it returning a promise? Yet I have used async/await? Plus according to the mongoose docs using `exec()` [makes a query a promise](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). How can I get the resolved promise?

Comment: You've made a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62486046/vs-code-how-can-i-use-the-run-code-command-to-query-my-database), stating that your code worked fine and it was a Visual Studio Code issue. `.exec()` must return a promise to work with [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). The fact that you're using VSCode to run Node doesn't change this.

Comment: What I meant by saying is that, the code has no issue yet I am not getting the required results. Await and async work, the issue seems to be with the mongoose query.